# Django Server Slow due to Warnings

Tags: python, django

Requesting for a page and executing the first line in the function in views.py  had significant delay . The reason I got from log files is possibly two warning messages I recieve every time that function in views.py is called.

Two doubts:
1) There is no import statement in the view function. Why would I get an import related warning everytime
2) How do I fix these errors and make my server fast.

```
[py.warnings]- WARNING- 2014-02-22 13:46:32,989  __init__.py: 11 - /home/ubuntu/crsq-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/oldnumeric/__init__.py:11: ModuleDeprecationWarning: The oldnumeric module will be dropped in Numpy 1.9
```

warnings.warn(_msg, ModuleDeprecationWarning)

```
[py.warnings]- WARNING- 2014-02-22 13:46:34,002  pkg_resources.py: 1054 - /home/ubuntu/crsq-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py:1054: UserWarning: /home/ubuntu/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
```